# How to Sum two columns and merge it into one?

Tags: merge, qlikview

Right now my table is like:
[image]

But I want to show my table like:
[image]

I want to show the values in a single column for Shipment and Receipt, new to Qlikview so dont have any idea. Need guidance. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this question needs more details for others to be able to help you. Maybe include a screen shot of the 'Table Viewer', and perhaps show some of the expressions that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is in the data model itself. 'Locked Trips S' is only referring to the 'Shipment' but has a value in 'Receipt' too. That shouldn't be a connection between these fields. Maybe provide a short screenshot of your data. That would help a lot :) !

And what about the 'Not Loaded Trips'? Where/How do you get it?

I would have commented this but I don't have the privilege :)

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved, there is a column in database that contains the values - Shipment and Receipt,I used that column as dimension and removed null values with this calculated dimension:

```
=if([Transaction Type]<>' ',[Transaction Type])
```

and then in expression I wrote the expression **=Count({})** as required.

Comment: this does not remove null values, it does remove values with a space in it